# Macbook Pro Randomly restarting after RAM upgrade

Tags: macos, upgrade, crash

I upgraded to 8 GB of ram today from 4 GB and my macbook is restarting randomly in about 10 minutes after booting

Here's the crash log

Hope someone can help

```
Thu Jun 18 20:00:39 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80045fef12): "Possible memory corruption: pmap_pv_remove(0xffffff801e8624e0,0x7fff75c21000,0x80000, 0x80000000, 0xffffff810d413484, 0xfffffeb7a63ef108): null pv_list!"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/osfmk/i386/pmap_internal.h:768
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810d413340 : 0xffffff800452bda1
0xffffff810d4133c0 : 0xffffff80045fef12
0xffffff810d4134b0 : 0xffffff80045ff645
0xffffff810d413510 : 0xffffff80045ad505
0xffffff810d413620 : 0xffffff80045a319c
0xffffff810d413650 : 0xffffff800454ea23
0xffffff810d413670 : 0xffffff8004a31cfd
0xffffff810d4137a0 : 0xffffff80049bf4df
0xffffff810d413c20 : 0xffffff80049bdc43
0xffffff810d413ce0 : 0xffffff80049bcd86
0xffffff810d413f50 : 0xffffff8004a4ba86
0xffffff810d413fb0 : 0xffffff8004635376

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: xpcproxy

Mac OS version:
14D131

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 241072887514
last loaded kext at 80727470559: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f86d6d000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
com.karios.driver.DuetDisplay   1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC      1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim        1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager        4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog       1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver       272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA       272.18
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin        1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient        3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV        1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver        4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP     2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl        3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl       1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics       10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC       1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU       4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport     4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri     10.0.6
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor        3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons      240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController      327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver       240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard     240.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck        471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless     1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache     36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient      3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter     404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage      2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough       1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331       800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC      1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360       930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager       161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons       3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC       2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET      1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC      1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient     218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall       161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib     272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin      1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink        4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface       97.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily       4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController     272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily     272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily        2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC       3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice       3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch     245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub       705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite      705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily       1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily      1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily       1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily        4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI       2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily     4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily        4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily      3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily     720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime        2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily     2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox      300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch       1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity       1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages     396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore       28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform      3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily     2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto        1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm      1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Here is the report Generated By Etresoft

```
Problem description:
random restart

EtreCheck version: 2.2 (132)
Report generated 6/18/15, 10:00 PM
Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck

Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

Hardware Information: ℹ️
    MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) (Technical Specifications)
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro9,2
    1 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2-core
    8 GB RAM Upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
    Wireless:  en1: 802.11 a/b/g/n
    Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 325 - SN = W02234GKVD3LC

Video Information: ℹ️
    Intel HD Graphics 4000
        Color LCD 1280 x 800

System Software: ℹ️
    OS X 10.10.3 (14D131) - Time since boot: 1:38:48

Disk Information: ℹ️
    APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384 disk0 : (500.11 GB)
        EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
        Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 
        BOOTCAMP (disk0s4) /Volumes/BOOTCAMP : 157.00 GB (156.96 GB free)
        Macintosh HD (disk1) / : 341.88 GB (65.46 GB free)
            Core Storage: disk0s2 342.25 GB Online

    HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N  

USB Information: ℹ️
    Logitech USB Receiver 
    SanDisk USB Flash Drive 8 GB
        WININSTALL (disk2s1) /Volumes/WININSTALL : 8.00 GB (2.63 GB free)
    Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 
    Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
    Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver 
    Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 

Thunderbolt Information: ℹ️
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Gatekeeper: ℹ️
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: ℹ️
        /Library/Extensions
    [loaded]    com.karios.driver.DuetDisplay (1 - SDK 10.10) [Click for support]

Startup Items: ℹ️
    HWNetMgr: Path: /Library/StartupItems/HWNetMgr
    HWPortDetect: Path: /Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect
    StartOuc: Path: /Library/StartupItems/StartOuc
    Startup items are obsolete in OS X Yosemite

Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [not loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusagent.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist [Click for support]

Launch Daemons: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.adobe.SwitchBoard.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusdaemon.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.teamviewer.Helper.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist [Click for support]

User Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]

User Login Items: ℹ️
    iTunesHelper    Application  (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)
    Airmail 2    Application  (/Applications/Airmail 2.app)
    Google Chrome    Application  (/Applications/Google Chrome.app)
    Evernote    Application  (/Applications/Evernote.app)
    Android File Transfer Agent    Application  (/Users/[redacted]/Library/Application Support/Google/Android File Transfer/Android File Transfer Agent.app)
    Alfred 2    Application  (/Applications/Alfred 2.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 17.0.0.188 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
    Flash Player: Version: 17.0.0.188 - SDK 10.6 Outdated! Update
    AdobePDFViewer: Version: 10.1.1 [Click for support]
    Default Browser: Version: 600 - SDK 10.10
    SharePointBrowserPlugin: Version: 14.0.0 [Click for support]
    Unity Web Player: Version: UnityPlayer version 5.0.1f1 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    JavaAppletPlugin: Version: 15.0.0 - SDK 10.10 Check version

3rd Party Preference Panes: ℹ️
    Flash Player  [Click for support]

Time Machine: ℹ️
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ℹ️
         7%    WindowServer
         2%    Mail
         2%    SystemUIServer
         1%    fontd
         0%    taskgated

Top Processes by Memory: ℹ️
    709 MB    kernel_task
    516 MB    softwareupdated
    434 MB    Google Chrome Helper(4)
    188 MB    mdworker(5)
    180 MB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent(2)

Virtual Memory Information: ℹ️
    1.30 GB    Free RAM 
    6.69 GB    Used RAM 
    0 B    Swap Used 

Diagnostics Information: ℹ️
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:18:31 PM    Self test - passed
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:02:51 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/fontd_2015-06-18-200251_[redacted].crash
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:02:50 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/fontd_2015-06-18-200250_[redacted].crash
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:02:49 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ReportCrash_2015-06-18-200249_[redacted].crash
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:01:42 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/hidd_2015-06-18-200142_[redacted].crash
    Jun 18, 2015, 08:00:41 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2015-06-18-200041_[redacted].panic [Click for details]
    Jun 18, 2015, 04:23:39 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/accountsd_2015-06-18-162339_[redacted].crash
    Jun 16, 2015, 07:04:28 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/locationd_2015-06-16-190428_[redacted].crash
    Jun 16, 2015, 04:08:28 PM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/cloudd_2015-06-16-160828_[redacted].crash
```

**EDIT:** Safe Boot Has resolved My problem, Thanks

Comment: If you boot in Safe mode dos it work than?

Comment: Let me try. Just a minute

Comment: Also in that crash report you cut of the bottom part where it says RAM .... Could you run the Apple Hardware test? I can not fix your hardware but we can try to find out if a software is making the problem.

Comment: How can I do the hardware test?

Comment: I booted in safe mode and restarted, since the boot it hasn't restarted. I hope it has solved the problem, but still to be sure can you tell me how to do the hardware test?

Comment: As I thought, you have a software problem not RAM. To run Apple hardware test, depending on your Model and OS X you might already have it installed. Hold the "D" during start up.

Comment: OK, so is it a coincidence this software problem happened just after ram upgrade or it might have been related?

Comment: Sometimes it is enough to boot in safe mode to fix minor problems. Take not of this small app that will generate your system report called Etersoft. http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck it is good for overview and some troubleshooting.

Comment: OK I'll take a look! Do you want me to post the results of the diagnosis?

Comment: Yes, please do that, publish it.

Comment: the report is too long to  post as comment what should i do?

Comment: Post it in you Question :)

Comment: "Safe Boot has fixed my problem" isn't really a description of what solved the problem! Did you find the problem by using safe boot, or are you still only able to work in safe boot mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step in Troubleshooting to do is to start in Safe mode. (Hold Shift during start up)

That will eliminate 99% of foreign applications causing the problem.

That will also show if it is a hardware problem. Sometimes it is enough to start in Safe mode to fix small problems.

If problem continues, run the Apple Hardware test, that might show problems with hardware. (hold "D" during start up).

For more clearer picture of your system, I recommend to run the EterSoft analytical tool. [EtreCheck is a simple little app to display the important details of your system configuration](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve hardware RAM issues is to isolate this around one of the sticks of RAM. This is most likely a hardware issue, that will only show as a bunch of random software impacts, making it really hard to diagnose.

Remove all the RAM, and put in only one new 4GB stick in, then start the Mac. If it boots and runs, then you have a good stick. Try the other one.

If the Mac won't boot with either, then try mixing a 2GB with a 4GB stick, as you already know your 2x 2GB sticks work. (sometimes you need both DIMM slots filled).

Answer (score 0):

Your Etrecheck report shows the RAM to be OK.

> 8 GB RAM Upgradeable
>
> ```
>     BANK 0/DIMM0
>
>         4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
>
>     BANK 1/DIMM0
>
>         4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
> ```

It also shows some obsoleted start up items that you can remove.

> Startup Items:
>
> ```
> HWNetMgr: Path: /Library/StartupItems/HWNetMgr
>
> HWPortDetect: Path: /Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect
>
> StartOuc: Path: /Library/StartupItems/StartOuc
>
> Startup items are obsolete in OS X Yosemite
> ```

Comment: After a long session of using my Macbook it again restarted without any warning and I did a hardware test, but there were no issues, now I am doing an extended hardware test. Is it possible that the problem must be hardware?